# Is SQL Injection possible when using PDO quote()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

I have following code (simple version of it):

```
$query = "SELECT *
FROM text
WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('".$pdo->quote($_GET["q"])."' IN BOOLEAN MODE);";
```

Is there any way to overcome the quote()-function and inject SQL into the query - or is quote() 100% safe?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @chris85, I´m sorry - I edited the title and tags. I'm a little tired. ;)

Comment: That's the point of it. Better yet is using parameterised queries: `AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Comment: `->quote()` adds the single quotes itself.

Answer (score 1):

> PDO::quote() places quotes around the input string (if required) and **escapes special characters** within the input string, using a **quoting style appropriate** to the underlying driver.

So it would appear it protects against SQL injection.
Although, prepared statements guarantee SQL injection protection as we can read from PHP manual:

> If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are strongly recommended to use **PDO::prepare()** to prepare SQL statements with bound parameters **instead of using PDO::quote()** to interpolate user input into an SQL statement. Prepared statements with bound parameters are not only more portable, more convenient, **immune to SQL injection**, but are often much faster to execute than interpolated queries, as both the server and client side can cache a compiled form of the query.

You can read a lot more about it at http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php